# MediaWiki: Show newest Pages from an Category

Tags: mediawiki

We are organizing most of our work inside an self hosted MediaWiki Installation. Now we want to show an overview page for an category, where the visitor can see the newest pages/changes from this categorys.

Like:

Category: PHP

- New Page: Added Documentation
- Changes to PHP 5.

Is there any built function or an working plugin available? I know about the possibilty to show recent changes on all kinds of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should use **DynamicPageList**:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList

Wikinews from Wikimedia uses it and it's well documented and tested.